# Using Gentella bootstrap theme in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use the [Gentelella](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella) theme with MVC but I can't get it to work right, and I feel like I'm defining the bundles incorrectly. I copied the HTML code exactly as it was in the sample and I get this:

[Bad layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOeek.png)

There shouldn't be any margins - I want it to appear how it does on the GitHub page. I define the bundle like so (admin being what I renamed the build files as):

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/admin").Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/admin.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/admin").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/admin.css",
            "~/Content/font-awesome.css"));
```

Comment: This isn't enough information to determine the problem. You will need to make sure that there is no other css linked to your project that could be fighting with the Gentellella theme as well as making sure that your HTML is structured correctly and has the right classes and ids

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out.  This is pretty much a clean MVC project made from Visual Studio.  Do you know offhand of anything Visual Studio generates that might conflict with a bootstrap theme?

Comment: Hopefully I can help but off the top of my head I know that most MVC projects come with bootstrap and a site css file (found in content). Note that all bootstrap version are not created equal. I would suggest removing the css bundle from your Views -> Shared -> Layout file and then adding in the files you got from your Gentelella package. You might want to do a little inspecting on their example site and make sure your layout file contains the same html markup. (F12) to inspect in most browsers.

Comment: I would specifically look at the way the "container" class is affecting your layout by using the inspector. I imagine there's a max width or margin in play.